# Image not displaying on ImageView

Tags: android, imageview

Image is not displaying in the `ImageView`. I can select image or take a photo of a new image but the image will not show in `ImageView`.

```
public class RequestQuoteFragment extends Fragment {


ImageButton mPostImage;
ImageView imageView;
private EditText mDescription, mWidth, mLength, mHeight;
Integer REQUEST_CAMERA = 1, SELECT_FILE = 2;

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_request_quotes, container, false);

    imageView = view.findViewById(R.id.image_view);

    mDescription = view.findViewById(R.id.item_description);
    mWidth = view.findViewById(R.id.width);
    mLength = view.findViewById(R.id.length);
    mHeight = view.findViewById(R.id.height);

    mPostImage = view.findViewById(R.id.attach_file);
    mPostImage.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            attachFile();
        }
    });

    getActivity().getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_PAN);

    return view;

}

//Attach Activity to fragments
private Context mContext;
@Override
public void onAttach(final Activity activity) {
    super.onAttach(activity);
    mContext = activity;
}

private void attachFile() {
    final CharSequence[] items = {"Camera", "Gallery", "Cancel"};

    AlertDialog.Builder builder;
    builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(mContext);
    builder.setTitle("Add Image");
    builder.setItems(items, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
            if(items[i].equals("Camera")) {

                Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CAMERA);

            } else if (items[i].equals("Gallery")) {

                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
                intent.setType("image/*");
                startActivityForResult(intent.createChooser(intent,"Select Photo"), SELECT_FILE);

            } else if (items[i].equals("Cancel")) {
                dialogInterface.dismiss();
            }
        }
    });
    builder.show();
}

@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);


    if (requestCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
        if (requestCode == REQUEST_CAMERA) {

            Bundle bundle = data.getExtras();
            final Bitmap bitmap = (Bitmap) bundle.get("data");
            imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);

        } else if (requestCode == SELECT_FILE) {

            Uri selectImageUri = data.getData();
            imageView.setImageURI(selectImageUri);


        }
    }
}

//reset fields
private void resetFields() {
    //UniversalImageLoader.setImage("", mPostImage);
    mDescription.setText("");
    mWidth.setText("");
    mLength.setText("");
    mHeight.setText("");
}

}
```

Comment: Can you use other libraries like Glide? It is much efficient

Comment: Both of them not working? Have you checked the bitmap value using breakpoints?

Comment: Both of them are not working. @matio how do I use Glide libraries? I am new to android.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Loading image using Glide is as follows:
https://github.com/codepath/android_guides/wiki/Displaying-Images-with-the-Glide-Library

Answer (score 0):

This one worked for me.

```
Intent getIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT).setType("image/*");

Intent pickIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
pickIntent.setType("image/*");

Intent chooserIntent = Intent.createChooser(getIntent, "Select Profile Image");
chooserIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_INITIAL_INTENTS, new Intent[] {pickIntent});

startActivityForResult(chooserIntent, AppConstants.PICK_IMAGE);
```

**And**

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if(resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK && requestCode == AppConstants.PICK_IMAGE)
    {
        image.setImageURI(data.getData());
    }
}
```

**Edited**

Otherwise

> startActivityForResult(intent.createChooser(intent,"Select Photo"), SELECT_FILE);

Change above line to

```
startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent,"Select Photo"), SELECT_FILE);
```

Answer (score 0):

There a small mistake on your code, that you have to check, *resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK*, instead of *requestCode == Activity.RESULT_OK*

Hope it will help your issue. Thanks!

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);


    if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
        if (requestCode == REQUEST_CAMERA) {

            Bundle bundle = data.getExtras();
            final Bitmap bitmap = (Bitmap) bundle.get("data");
            imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);

        } else if (requestCode == SELECT_FILE) {

            Uri selectImageUri = data.getData();
            imageView.setImageURI(selectImageUri);


        }
    }
}
```